# Firebase: best way to order and filter multiple childs

Tags: javascript, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So as we know firebase won't let order by multiple childs. I'm looking for a solution to filter my data so at the end I will be able to limit it to 1 only. So if I won't to get the lowest price it will be something like that:

```
ref.orderByChild("price").limitToFirst(1).on...
```

The problem is that I also need to filter it by dates (timestamp)

so for that only I will do:

```
.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startValue).endAt(endValue).on...
```

So for now that's my query and then I'm running on all results and checking for that one row that has the lowest price. my Data is pretty big and contains around 100,000 rows. I can changed it however I want.

for the first query that gets the lowest price but all timestamps causes that the returned row might be the lowest price but not in my dates range. However this query takes ONLY 2 seconds compared to the second one which takes 20 including my code to get the lowest price.

So, what are your suggestions on how to do it best? I know I can make another index which contains the timestamp and the price but those are different data values and it makes it impossible.

full data structure:

```
country
    store
        item
            price,
            timestamp
```

just to make it even more clear, I have 2 inner loops which runs over all countries and then over all stores. so the real query is something like that:

```
ref.child(country[i]).child(store[j]).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startValue).endAt(endValue).on...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't immediately see a way to combine these values. If you can figure out how an increase of the price by 1 correlates to an increase of the timestamp, you might be able to do something similar to Geohashes: combining two well defined numbers into a single, lexicographically orderable string. But I admit that (while it'd definitely be an interesting experiment) it's a bit beyond what I can conjure up here.

Comment: Thanks Frank, Appreciate your comment. Do you think that structuring it same as the countries and stores (country -> store -> timestamp -> item) and then querying would be too much? then I will have 3 loops... :/